# Charting library that does not cause memory leak when updating chart

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, charts, jqplot

I want to build a page with interactively refreshing charts based on the data that is being fetched from the server asynchronously using AJAX. I really like [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com), but when trying to update the graph periodically (by calling `replot()`, without page refresh), it causes a huge browser memory leak. It seems to be a well known issue occurring on all major browsers.

I haven't tried [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot) and [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis), but quick googling reveals that they seem to have the same problems.

Are you aware of any JavaScript charting library that does not introduce memory leak after several updates of the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). A [quick googling](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=highcharts+memory+leak) doesn't seem to indicate that memory leaks are much of an issue.

Comment: I knew about Highcharts but I haven't tried it previously as it's not free for commercial use. But after your answer I changed my mind and I must admit it works exactly the way I wanted, thanks!

Comment: highcharts has memory leaks: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13365

Answer (score 0):

to avoid jqPlot memory leak you have to remove binding and destry your chart:

```
var chart;

function yourTimedFunction(data) {
    if (chart) 
    {
        $('#chartDiv *').unbind(); // iexplorer
        chart.destroy();
    }
    chart = $.jqplot('chartDiv', ............. ); 
}
```