# Speed comparison of JavaScript charting libraries

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, charts, svg

I am working on a dynamic report where charts need to be recreated on demand, because of data changes or analysis needs.

I'd be interested in a speed comparison of JavaScript charting tools currently available on the market.

I am working with a few thousand data points that I need to slice and dice across dimensions (date, market, type, customer).

Comment: See also: [Charting library that does not cause memory leak when updating chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291049)

Comment: One thing for sure: Google Chart Tools are really slow for such amount of data points (although they are powerful to display any information in graphic way)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at these:

http://jsperf.com/search?q=chart

The only one I can see there that would be any use for you is flot vs. raphael, though. Of course you can always try to build on top of that and write your own tests for other libs you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the existing test seems to be broken.

Comment: The link is broken, can you update?