# High performance JavaScript chart API for Mobile applications through HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, charts

I'm working on a cross-platform mobile application through MoSync. Regarding a JavaScript chart for displaying data come from Bluetooth in the mobile device, I need a JavaScript chart API which has a very high rendering speed and performance. It should be fast enough to draw/redraw/update the chart as the data will be injected to the Webview. AFAIK from testing couple of APIs, data injection reduce the speed in the mobile applications. FFI, following points could be helpful to show how fast the chart should be in order to run smoothly in the application.

1. **Update:** every 500ms or possibly 250ms
2. **New data per update:** three arrays with size 50 for three series
3. **Data traverse** (from Bluetooth to chart API): c++ >> UI (HTML) >> WebView >> chart API

Note that I am aware of tons of available JavaScript chart APIs, however I need a piece of advice which has considered the explained situation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Below you'll find my research. Hopefully, this helps you find a solution.

1. [Comparison of JavaScript Data Visualization Libraries](http://kraskniga.blogspot.com/2012/06/comparison-of-javascript-data.html) specifically says that [flotr2](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/index) is built for performance. It was posted on June, 2012.

   > **Mobile friendly:** Yes, built for performance and includes touch events / multi touch
   >
   > **Interesting features:** extensible plugin framework, tuned for performance. JSON api,
   >   programmable for interactivity
2. [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/javascript-charts): Notable solution that specifically addresses performance and mobile issues. [They have a whole page breaking down how they achieve superior performance.](http://www.rgraph.net/docs/improving-performance.html)
3. [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/): The comparison article [13 Chart and Graph plotting javascript plugins](http://www.queness.com/post/10781/13-chart-and-graph-plotting-javascript-plugins) states that "special care has been taken to optimize the performance." However, I didn't see anything on the site about mobile support.
4. > You might want to have a look at these:
   >
   > http://jsperf.com/search?q=chart
   >
   > The only one I can see there that would be any use for you is flot vs.
   >   raphael, though. Of course you can always try to build on top of that
   >   and write your own tests for other libs you're interested in.

   via https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900526/1085891
5. Unfortunately, [Javascript Graphs and Charts libraries](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries) comparison does not have a performance criteria but I thought might still be helpful.
6. Another via r/programming: https://canvasjs.com

**Extra:** [JavaScript Performance On Mobile Devices](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/11-10-07/javascript_performance_on_mobile_devices.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. flotr2 works smoothly on my mobile application and its performance is awesome since I tried to add three arrays with size 100 every 250ms. Unbelievable :)

Comment: This is a a little bit outdated info? The links don't much work. WebGL charts give much higher performance than plain HTML5 Canvas rendered charts. Performance tester results (https://www.arction.com/js-performance-tester-results/) show millions of data points can be rendered in mobile devices today.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another High Performance Charting Library called [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com)

It renders over 100,000 datapoints in [100-200ms](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/intro/high-performance-javascript-charts/). Because it is based on Canvas, it works on most modern devices.

Answer (score 3):

I've had excellent experiences with the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) charting library with large datasets (up to 10000 points).  It uses SVG and VML for rendering, which is much faster than canvas based solutions.  Plus, because it doesn't use flash, it will work on most mobile devices.

Comment: How it handle realtime data? In my experience, with calling addPoint() to add new points every second (or few times a second) it leaks a lot of memory

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I also used highcharts, but the long delay problem is still available while trying to update the series by injecting JavaScript code into the webview and then calling addPoint() method.

Comment: Try calling `Series#setData()` instead, and just update the data for the entire series.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/), it has an impressive demo. Tested it on briefly on phones, feels good man.

See also [comparison of relevant projects](https://www.openhub.net/p/compare?project_0=Flotr2&project_1=Flot&project_2=dygraphs&submit_2=Go).

Answer (score 0):

[LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/) has WebGL rendering, and optimized for real-time streaming data. For web, it offers excellent performance, and millions of data points / sec can be added in to chart while keeping high FPS rate.

- [Performance tester](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-performance/)
- [Real-time scrolling data](https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-streamingData)
- [Waveform and spectrum computation example](https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-audio)

[I'm the tech lead of LightningChart components]

Answer (score 0):

I've found two charting libraries so far which are able to handle datasets with 100k points smoothly. (even with panning and zooming)

#### PlotlyJS

I was surprised to find that [Plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js), in SVG mode, was able to handle 100k points, with realtime panning and zooming, with ease: https://codepen.io/Venryx/pen/eYzpEzN

Demo's core code below:

```
const line = {
    x: [],
    y: [],

    // uncomment this line to disable the data simplify/decimate optimization
    //line: {simplify: false},

    // use 'scattergl' for WebGL renderer; though this seems to break updates to data
    type: 'scatter',
};

updateData(1000);
function updateData(yRange) {
    line.x = [];
    line.y = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      line.x.push(i);
      line.y.push(Math.sin(i / 500) * yRange);
    }

    // if calling a second time, add code here to update the chart (see demo)
}

Plotly.newPlot('graph', [line]);
```

There are some WebGL-based charting libraries with better raw performance (ie. pre-data-decimation), such as [webgl-plot](https://github.com/danchitnis/webgl-plot) and [TimeChart](https://github.com/huww98/TimeChart); however, because Plotly.js comes with a fancy data [decimation/simplification option](https://community.plotly.com/t/polyline-simplification/1600), it ends up giving comparable performance. (and with fewer restrictions than those WebGL libs have -- for example, svg-mode Plotly lets you add and edit data entries after the initial render)

#### uPlot

[uPlot](https://github.com/leeoniya/uPlot) is the second charting library I found that can chart 100k+ datasets with ease.

As the point-count increases past around the 1 million mark, it actually starts exceeding the responsiveness of even Plotly. (especially for zooming, and adding/modifying data with the "Extend data" button)

Demo (designed to match the Plotly one above): https://codepen.io/Venryx/pen/qBNOoYO

(uPlot is now my library of choice for charts with extremely large datasets, ie. 1 million+.)