# How to create graph in hybrid application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hybrid

I am new to hybrid technology. Currently i am working on ionic framework, angular js and phone gap , My problem is how to crate graph.
can anyone suggest me how to crate graph (line , pie graph)

Regards
Deepti

Comment: What do you mean by hybrid technology?

Comment: As you said you're working on phonegap and ionic, seems you might want graphs and charts for mobile html5 apps, Check out some data visualization libraries written in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13944251/1177295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Using [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/)

They have responsive charts and the Data structure can be easily used with Factory or Service

**Data Structure**

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};
```