# Chart.js extremely slow on 8 series of 500+ points

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm trying to plot 8 series of line charts with chart.js but initial drawing, turning on/off seria by clicking on legend and/or adding some points to series all are extremely slow. Takes up to 10 seconds sometimes. Am I missing some magic "speedup property" in options or this is normal?

Actually I need to draw and update in real time about 10 series of 2000 points each, is this possible with some reasonable update time?

This is the example I'm playing with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-ex

Comment: Just wondering if this is something that angular can handle or if its just the library being unable to handle your data sets.Could you add another demo environment for the same chart and data, but just using plain js? In order to compare how well the lib behaves by itself

Comment: With that many data points, your data is unlikely to be meaningful. I would apply some logic to group and average out the data. I made a [vanilla JS Plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/0v2jAWsFC3vsRjChx3zt) to show that the performance is just as bad.

Comment: Unfortunately meaningful of this charts are determined by customers not me, and they want them this way. I'm now playing with other library - `Flot` (well known Grafana uses it). It performs 10 times faster even with 8x1350 points. Take a look if you interested: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flot-ex

Comment: I ended up ditching Chart.js for uPlot. This page has a link to demos showing it displaying 100k points, with realtime panning and zooming, with ease: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64337410/2441655 (I upped the count to 1 million, and it worked fine even then!)

Answer (score 2):

Applying chart options as described in [High Performance Line Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#high-performance-line-charts) to [your vanilla JS example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405271/chart-js-extremely-slow-on-8-series-of-500-points#comment99435750_56405271) renders a chart with no appreciable performance problems for me in Firefox 67.

```js
let labels = [];
let data1 = [];
let data2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  labels.push("l" + i);
  data1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  data2.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      //backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: data1
    }, {

      label: 'My First dataset',
      //backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 132)',
      data: data2

    }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 0 // general animation time
    },
    hover: {
      animationDuration: 0 // duration of animations when hovering an item
    },
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```